# How to access returned value of a chained variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class that supports the following API:

```cpp
auto &&container = TestContainer::create().add("Hello").add("World");
```

So, I created a class where the `add` functions returns reference to instance:

```cpp
class TestContainer {
  public:
    std::vector<String> values;
        
    TestContainer &add(const String &string) {
      values.push_back(string);
      return *this;
    }
        
        
    static TestContainer create() {
      return TestContainer();
    }
};
```

However, for some reason when I access `container` variable, the vector inside it is empty. So, I tried another approach:

```cpp
auto &&container = TestContainer::create();

container.add("Hello").add("World");
```

This one works because I am referencing the original container; however, when I try to reference the "last" container in the chain, the reference is lost and destructor is called.

What can I do here to achieve the API where I don't need to split `create` from `add`?

Comment: `auto &&container = ...`-> `auto container = ...`?

Comment: Already answered, but you're creating a reference to temporary which is immediately destroyed. (A reference to temporary sometimes extends the temporary's lifetime, but this is a case where it can't.)

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `&&` in the declaration of the `container` variable?

Try

```
auto container=TestContainer::create().add()...;
```

or better still:

```
auto container=TestContainer().add(...).add(...);
```

There is no need for a create function.

Some more info:
`TestContainer()` creates a new (temporary) object of type `TestContainer`. `.add(...)` calls the `add` function on this new (temporary) object and pushes a value to the member. It returns a reference to itself, so you can chain calls to `add`.

Then, finally, when you are done calling add, the temporary object gets assigned to the object `container`. Or rather - as the compiler is allowed to optimize the = away, a new object is created from the temporary object.

```
TestContainer container(TestContainer().add().add().add());
```

would work just as well.

Comment: Can you please explain why using reference or rvalue reference is wrong? I don't want the created object to be copied.

Comment: @Gasim You're creating a reference to **what**?

Comment: The mechanism is called "Copy elision". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision
When you 'assign' a newly created object with a call to a constructor, the compiler is allowed to skip the assignment and initialize the new object instead.

The same thing happens with return values

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why `auto&& container = TestContainer::create();` works. `container` is a reference here, too.

Answer (score 1):

The chaining of the member functions breaks the extending of the lifetime after the chain ends.

What you could do is something like this:

```
class TestContainer {
  public:
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    
    TestContainer & add(const std::string &string) & {
        values.push_back(string);
        return *this;
    }
    
    TestContainer add(const std::string &string) && {
      values.push_back(string);
      return std::move(*this);
    }
        
    static TestContainer create() {
      return TestContainer();
    }
};    

int main()
{
    auto &&container = TestContainer::create().add("Hello").add("World");
   
}
```

Or this:

```
class TestContainer {
  public:
    std::vector<std::string> values;
  
    TestContainer & add(const std::string &string) {
        values.push_back(string);
        return *this;
    }

    TestContainer end_chain() & { return std::move(*this); } 
        
    static TestContainer create() {
      return TestContainer();
    }
};    

int main()
{
    auto &&container = TestContainer::create().add("Hello").add("World").end_chain();
   
}
```

Both solutions have gotchas. For the first one you have code duplication, for the second one you need to know that you have to call `end_chain`.

And it will create an additional object. But the contents of the `std::vector` member can be moved.